# Sublime Text error with: Packages\User\Plain text.sublime-settings:1:27

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Error trying to parse Sublime Text 3 settings.

> Unexpected trailing characters in Packages\User\Plain text.sublime-settings:1:27

This error occur every time I open Sublime Text 3.

I have tried reinstalling it three times and the same issue occurs again and again.

> Preference > settings

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/User/SublimeLinter/Monokai (SL).tmTheme",
    "font_size": 13,
    "dpi_scale": 1.0,
    "font_face": "Consolas",
    "font_size": 12,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "line_padding_bottom": 1,
    "line_padding_top": 1,
    "tab_size": 4,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "word_wrap": "true",
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

> The default settings below and the issue occur with this setting too.

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/User/SublimeLinter/Monokai (SL).tmTheme"
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about software problem

Comment: A program complains that there's an error with a certain settings file, and you go to a web site to get some help. Did it *ever* cross your mind to **include the contents of that file** so we could help you?

Comment: I dont know where is the setting file. I did not set any thing in sublime and I reinstall it three times that the issue occur everytime when I open it after I finish installation.

Comment: `Packages\User\Plain text.sublime-settings:1:27` means line 1 column 27. Show the contents of `Packages\User\Plain text.sublime-settings` Go to `Menu > Preferences > Browse Packages...` go to the the `User` directory and look a file named `Plain text.sublime-settings`.

Comment: Thanks Gerard Roche. I find this file and I remove it then the issue is gone. Though I did not remember what is in that file.

Answer (score 0):

`Packages\User\Plain text.sublime-settings:1:27` means line `1` column `27`.

There is a syntax error in the file `Packages\User\Plain text.sublime-settings` at line `1` column `27`.

All `*.sublime-settings` files are JSON.

To locate the file:

1. Go to `Menu > Preferences > Browse Packages...`
2. Go to the the `User` directory
3. Look a file named `Plain text.sublime-settings`

Correct the syntax error or delete the file.